# Shuffle one column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

How does one shuffle only one column of data in pandas?

I have a Dataframe with production data that I want to load onto dev for testing.  However, the data contains personally identifiable information so I want to shuffle those columns.

Columns: FirstName LastName Birthdate SSN OtherData

If the original dataframe is created by read_csv and I want to translate the data into a second dataframe for sql loading but shuffle first name, last name, and SSN, I would have expected to be able to do this:

```
if devprod == 'prod':
    #do not shuffle data
    df1['HS_FIRST_NAME'] = df[4]
    df1['HS_LAST_NAME'] = df[6]
    df1['HS_SSN'] = df[8]
else:
    df1['HS_FIRST_NAME'] = np.random.shuffle(df[4])
    df1['HS_LAST_NAME'] = np.random.shuffle(df[6])
    df1['HS_SSN'] = np.random.shuffle(df[8])
```

However, when I try that I get the following error:

**A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame**

Comment: Please see the linked post, particularly [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53954986/4909087).

Comment: In addition to resolving the error, an alternative way to shuffle with pandas is to use `df.sample(frac=1)`.  E.g. `df1['HS_FIRST_NAME'] = df[4].sample(frac=1)`.

Comment: df[4].sample(frac=1) runs without error but does not appear to shuffle the data.

Comment: Just curious ... where in that 10,000 line answer does he point out how to shuffle one column of data in a dataframe? :D

Comment: The answer is that it could be as simple as numpy.random.shuffle(df['column_name']).  However, Python will throw a warning because pandas does not want you to alter columns that are indexed.  The better way is to create a numpy array and then shuffle (  myarry = df['column_name'].values  /n numpy.random.shuffle(myarray) ).   If you need to then insert that data into a dataframe, you simply convert it back to series ( df['randomized_column'] = pd.Series(myarray)

Comment: @coldspeed, I reopened this one, felt there is a trivial way to amend OP's algorithm to do what they want. Possibly an XY problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The immediate error is a symptom of using an inadvisable approach when working with dataframes.

[`np.random.shuffle`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.shuffle.html) works in-place and returns `None`, so assigning to the output of `np.random.shuffle` will not work. In fact, in-place operations are rarely required, and often yield no material benefits.

Here, for example, you can use [`np.random.permutation`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.permutation.html) and use NumPy arrays via [`pd.Series.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) rather than series:

```
if devprod == 'prod':
    #do not shuffle data
    df1['HS_FIRST_NAME'] = df[4]
    df1['HS_LAST_NAME'] = df[6]
    df1['HS_SSN'] = df[8]
else:
    df1['HS_FIRST_NAME'] = np.random.permutation(df[4].values)
    df1['HS_LAST_NAME'] = np.random.permutation(df[6].values)
    df1['HS_SSN'] = np.random.permutation(df[8].values)
```

Answer (score 19):

This also appears to do the job:

```
df1['HS_FIRST_NAME'] = df[4].sample(frac=1).values
```

Comment: Note that .values or .to_numpy() after .sample is mandatory, otherwise original column gets saved without shuffling.